# I pushed Knight Lautrec of Carim off a cliff, how to get the loot?

Tags: dark-souls

At Firelink Shrine [Lautrec](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/knight-lautrec-of-carim) didn't start fighting me after two hits, so I kicked him off the ledge. Now his loot is off the side of the hill, and I can't get to it. Or is there some way to get to it?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/222021/73976)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is enough to reload your save after pushing him off the Cliff. After reloading his loot will be right where he was.

Comment: @l0b0 I can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr: Got them! Keep dying and going back, and the items should appear.

1. I tried jumping off and pressing <kbd>A</kbd> repeatedly to maybe catch the items during the fall, but that didn't work. Didn't even get the prompt.
2. Went back after respawning, and got my souls, then jumped off the ledge below in despair.
3. Went back *again*, and now the items were where Lautrec had been standing.